# IBM Assistant(Conversation) Error: SpelEvaluationException when evaluating dialog node ID

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I have a flow in my chatBot application where I switch workspaces and its giving me SpelEvaluationException error.

I have a router workspace that determine initial indent of the client, once I know the initial intend I route the next request to appropriate workspaces

```
Workspace Router :
      Bot :- Hey this is an awesome bot, what do you need help with 
              1. Apples 
              2. Bananas 
              3. Oranges 

      Client :- I need help with my apples 
      --- I pass a custom JSON from the workspace with tells my app to route next request to apples workspace ----

Apple Workspace :

      BOT: Hey what can I help you in apples .
```

The flow works fine but when I send request to Apples workspace. I get the following error in log_message .

```
SpelEvaluationException when evaluating dialog node ID [node_2_1517933972148]. The syntax of condition [intents[0].confidence < 0.50] is valid, but cannot be evaluated. Check that objects in expression are not null or out of bounds.\nSpEL evaluation error: EL1025E: The collection has '0' elements, index '0' is invalid\n
```

Answer (score 1):

So somehow you are asking Watson to evaluate the intents array before actually passing any input, so no intent data is returned, thus the spell expression fails and throws the error.

So however you are calling that second Apples workspace make sure you have input text being sent as well.

Comment: Or change the flow of your dialog so it does not evaluate that SpEL expression right away

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, you can try to jump by response so that the condition is not evaluated and check if you are not trying to save the intent in a variable inside the JSON. Possibly you already solved it but I leave my proposal hoping it will serve someone else.

Comment: Hello there, please this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that actually fix the askers issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).